# chrome.tabs.onUpdated reacting to iframes

Tags: google-chrome-extension

chrome.tabs.onUpdated is being called whenever a tab's URL changes or the URL of any of the iframes it contains are updated. Is this the expected result? Is there anyway to filter out iframes changing?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, simply use the second parameter of the [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) callback function:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.url) {
        // The URL changed, do something
    }
});
```

Comment: The if statement that you wrote will always be true. It does not filter out iframes loading

Comment: @BenMcCann No it's not always true. It is only set (thus *truthy*) if the URL of the main frame changes. I've just verified that the answer is correct in Chromium 23.

Comment: Ah, you're right. However, I'd like to perform some action on all page loads of the main page, but this does not work on page reloads.